# How to get vertex neighbors in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex, normals

I am trying to create an advanced shader for an AR application in Unity. Therefore I need all vertices and their neighbors from my gameobject (within a C# script). Getting the vertices is not the problem, but how do I get their neighbors(maybe with an indexbuffer)?
I am not new to shaders, but to shaders within Unity. 
After I got the neighbors I would like to pass them from a C# script to a function within a shader file. I guess that should be possible in Unity, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is by searching the triangle index. The pattern is always the same, always 3 indices define a vertex. since you know the index of your vertex, you can just search the triangle array and return the other two of any triangle, which will give you all vertices within the range of the desired one.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I will try that. And passing on parameters to shader functions from a C# file is also possible?

Comment: no, you can access verts from code, but vertex structures is opaque once you get to the fragment stage